# Cannot access private property of an object PHP

Tags: php, oop, private

I am currently working with Ratchet websocket and when I try to print out the connection I get this object and I want to get the `uri->query` field but when i try doing so it gives me an error that I can't access the private property.

My code:

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request {#772
  -method: "GET"
  -requestTarget: null
  -uri: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri {#773
    -scheme: "http"
    -userInfo: ""
    -host: "localhost"
    -port: 8090
    -path: "/"
    -query: "id=3"
    -fragment: ""
  }
    "Pragma" => array:1 [
      0 => "no-cache"
    ]
    "Cache-Control" => array:1 [
      0 => "no-cache"
    ]
    "Upgrade" => array:1 [
      0 => "websocket"
    ]
    "Origin" => array:1 [
      0 => "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
    ]
    "Sec-WebSocket-Version" => array:1 [
      0 => "13"
    ]
    "User-Agent" => array:1 [
      0 => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
    ]
    "Accept-Encoding" => array:1 [
      0 => "gzip, deflate, br"
    ]
    "Accept-Language" => array:1 [
      0 => "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,hy;q=0.6"
    ]
    "Sec-WebSocket-Key" => array:1 [
      0 => "apMgrSRt1GBHX5Nhj19gHQ=="
    ]
    "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions" => array:1 [
      0 => "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits"
    ]
  ]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: null
}
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Cannot access private property GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request::$uri

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_\my_project\app\Http\Controllers\WebSocketController.php:34
    30|
    31|     public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    32|     {
    33|
  > 34|         dd($conn->httpRequest->uri);
    35|
    36|         $this->clients->attach($conn);
    37|         $this->users[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;
    38|     }

  Exception trace:

  1   App\Http\Controllers\WebSocketController::onOpen(Object(Ratchet\WebSocket\WsConnection))
      C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_\my_project\vendor\cboden\ratchet\src\Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer.php:142

  2   Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer::onOpen(Object(Ratchet\Server\IoConnection), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
      C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_\my_project\vendor\cboden\ratchet\src\Ratchet\Http\HttpServer.php:51
```

How can I take the value of `query` field?

Comment: you should read about [variable scopes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: You can't access it directly because it is private. Check the docs, I'm sure there will be a method like getUri or getQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is private, so you cannot access it from outside the class. (Read about [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php))

But in your case, you are using a Guzzle HTTP request object, so as the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Guzzle.Http.Message.Request.html) says :

```
public getQuery ( mixed $asString = false )

Get the collection of key value pairs that will be used as the query string in the request
```

So you can just use getQuery to get the query from the object.

Comment: Do I have to write this inside of my function?

Comment: Use something like $conn->httpRequest->getQuery() or $conn->httpRequest->getQuery('uri')

Comment: This is my full object https://textuploader.com/11t43 I want to take the `httpRequest->uri->query` from it and store it in a variable.

Comment: I have tried `$conn->httpRequest->getQuery()` and `$conn->httpRequest->getQuery('uri')` but both give an error `Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request::getQuery()`

Comment: What about $conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access as follows:

```
$conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery();
```

[Read more here..](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Guzzle.Http.Message.Request.html)